# scraping a web page with python

Tags: python, screen-scraping

Here is the code, it produces what I want but not in the way I want to output the result

---

```
   import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_Florida'

    fl = requests.get(url)
    fl_soup = BeautifulSoup(fl.text, 'html.parser')
    block = fl_soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'bb-04em'})

    for name in fl_soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'bb-04em'}):
        print(name.text)
```

---

output

2020-04-21

27,869(+3.0%)

867

I would like the output like this
2020-04-21  27,869(+3.0%)  867

Comment: You just want it to print on the same line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_Florida'

fl = requests.get(url)
fl_soup = BeautifulSoup(fl.text, 'html.parser')

div_with_table = fl_soup.find('div', {'class': 'barbox tright'})
table = div_with_table.find('table')

for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    for cell in row.findAll('td', {'class': 'bb-04em'}):
        print(cell.text, end=' ')
    print()  # new line for each row
```

Comment: I get this now       2020-03-012(0)2020-03-022(+0%)02020-03-033(+50%)02020-03-048(+167%)02020-03-0717(+113%)22020-03-0818(+6%)22020-03-0919(+6%)  (Each should be one line but this is closer)

Comment: Check the new answer @kevinwholley

Comment: Thank you so much. that is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Before accesing each `<td>`, try to get the data by each `<tr>`, you will get the information of each table row. Then you could search inside `<td>` or whatever you want.

Comment: Can you help me with an example? I was looking at that but unclear how to get it? Thank you

Comment: Check @JackMoody anwser, it is the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

For the last print statement include the end parameter. By default the print statement has end='\n'

`print(name.text, end=' ')`

This would give you the desired output.